# How to make a CakePHP drop down list

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have searched this question a lot on here and none of the recognised answers are working for me. I want to populate a select drop down list in my view from another model. For some reason at the moment only the last record is displayed. I have one working solution but the code is long and ugly and i know there must be a better way. In my EventsController i have the following code

```
$this->loadModel('Guests');
$this->set('Guests', $this->Guests->find('All',array('fields'=>array('first_name'))));
```

As far as i understand this creates a variable called Guests that is an array containing the first names of the guests to an event. Then in my Events/index.ctp i have the following code to create a drop down list. The first example works but is long and ugly. The next three examples are all answers i have found on here but none of them are giving the desired out put. Examples 2 and 3 only show the last record in the table and example 4 displays nothing.

```
<---- This works ---->

<select>
    <?php foreach ($Guests as $Guests){ ?>
 1        <option value = "<?php echo $Guests['first_name'];?>">  <?php echo $Guests['first_name'];?></option> <?php } ?> 
</select>

<!--This does not work-->

   <?= $this->Form->create('Guests'); ?>

 2 <?= $this->Form->select('Guests', ['options' => $Guests['first_name']]);  ?>

 3 <?= $this->Form->input('Guests', array('options' => array('Guests' => $Guests['first_name']))); ?>

 4 <?= $this->Form->input('Guests', array('options' => $Guests)); ?>

  <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

I can see that the variable is being passed from the EventsController by viewing the variables with the cakePHP toolbar. I have included a screenshot of this for conformation. [Screenshot of variables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tob8L.png). As i am new to cakePHP i would appreciate someone guidance on where the problem is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How looks your relationships between Events and Guests models?

Comment: They are joined by another table called invite. Invite has I'd INT(11) event_id INT(11) guest_id INT(11) accepted TINYINT(1)

Comment: Edit your question and add (copy) from your Events Model all relationships (hasMany, hasOne, belongsTo,.. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `find list` instead.

Controller:

```
$this->set('guests',
    $this->Guests->find('list', array('fields' => array('first_name'))) 
);
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Guests');

echo $this->Form->input(
    'Guests.first_name',
    array(
        'options' => $guests
    )
);

echo $this->Form->end();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

Comment: I have used find list before while trying to fix this issue with no success. I have copied your code into my project and it produces and drop down list with no data in it. If i check the guests variable you created i can see that it is their but the value of each slot is null. Thanks for the help @bill

Comment: hm, what does your `guests` table look like?

Comment: I'd INT 11
first_name VARCHAR (255)
last_name VARCHAR (255)
email VARCHAR (255)
created DATETIME()
modified DATETIME();

This is how my guest table looks. I also have a table called Invites which has event_id and guest_id as foreign keys. Its weird becuase I can view the find('All') result in the cakePHP tool bar under variables. The problem is only the last record is visible in the drop down list on the view.

Comment: I doubt that this will solve the issue but it's possible that there are issues with your naming.  Model names should singular, so your `Guests` model should be renamed to `Guest`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: I was aware of that and planned to rectify it down the line. I have renamed Thanks @bill my models and rebaked them. I then copied the code across and i am still having the same issue. It looks as if i will have to just use the long ugly way. A note iv just thought may be relevant is that i am using mySQL workbench and not mysql phpmyadmin. Could it be that cakePHP has issues with mySQL workbench?

Answer (score 0):

```
First try to get list from table like 

1. suppose you have Users Controller and you are trying to show select option in add.ctp  then create

///in UsersController.php

function add(){

 $users = $this->Users->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','first_name'));

  $this->set(compact('users'));

 }

//in Template/Users/add.ctp (cakephp version 3) , in View/Users/add.ctp


echo $this->Form->input('Users.user_id',array(
        'options' => $users`enter code here`
    )); 

// when $users return an empty array this input become input type text otherwise it will be select option
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code need to user for getting values for user details and pass it to drop down menu.

```
$users = $this->MvacationServices->Users->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'username','limit' => 200]);
```